# How to check queue depth of a remote IBM MQ queue manager using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

How to check queue depth of a remote IBM MQ queue manager using Power Shell script?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like they have [cmdlets](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/574675) you can install and explore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on V9 you could use the REST API if you have MQWEB server running

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using 7.5 version.

Comment: I would seriously recommend looking at migrating to a later version if possible. V7.5 is no longer supported by IBM, which means any problems you encounter will not be able to be raised to IBM for support.